# Spectral decomposition of normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Define $T$ from $L_{2}(R)$ into itself by $T(f)(t)=f(t+1)$. Show that $T$ is normal and finds its spectral decomposition.
I've shown that $f$ is normal (in fact it's unitary) but how do I find its spectral decomposition? I know the decomposition is of the form $\int_{{\sigma}(T)} {\lambda}\,dE=T$ so I have presumably have to find the spectrum and the spectral measure. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ is unitary because (a) $\|Tf\|=\|f\|$ and (b) $T$ is onto. So $T^{\star}f=f(t-1)$ is the inverse of $T$. The spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is a subset of the unit circle in the complex plane. Let $f^{\wedge}$ denote the Fourier transform of $f$. Then
$$
    (Tf)^{\wedge}
        =l.i.m.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+1)e^{-ist}\,dt
        =l.i.m. \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-is(t-1)}\,dt
        =e^{-is}f^{\wedge}(s).
$$
The spectral resolution of the identity $P$ for $T$ is supported on the unit circle $C$ in the complex plane. If $E$ is a subset of $C$, let $p_{E}(s)=\chi_{E}(e^{is})$, where $\chi_{E}$ is the characteristic function of $E$. Then
$$
       P(E)f= (p_{E} f^{\wedge})^{\vee}.
$$
Check that $P$ is a spectral measure. For example, $P(C)=I$ because $P(C)f=(f^{\wedge})^{\vee}=f$. Because $p_{E}$ is real, $P(E)^{\star}=P(E)$. Fourier transform properties give $P(E)P(E')=P(E\cap E')$. Notice that $P(E)T=TP(E)$. And,
$$
                          \int_{C}\lambda dP(\lambda)f = Tf,
$$
which follows from integration, and follows intuitively from
$$TP(\{ e^{i\theta} : |\theta-\theta_{0}|<\delta\})f\approx e^{i\theta_{0}}P(\{ e^{i\theta} : |\theta-\theta_{0}|<\delta\})f.
$$

Comment: I am curious how the argument changes if we began by letting $A = \frac{d}{dx}$ on a dense subset of $L^{2}(\Bbb{R})$ (probably on $H^{1}(\Bbb{R})$, since we expect that $A$ is indeed essentially selfadjoint) and inspect the spectral measure of $A$. Because I am thinking of utilizing functional calculus to $T = e^{d/dx}$. Oh, also +1 upvote.

Comment: @sos440: Sorry, I missed your remark. Actually $A$ is antisymmetric. $iA$ is symmetric. In fact, $iA$ is selfadjoint on the domain consisting of functions $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ which are absolutely continuous with $f' \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. The spectral measure for $A=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ is $P(S)f=(\chi_{S}f^{\wedge})^{\vee}$.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. What I was actually thinking of was $A = D_{x} = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$, so you're absolutely right. Thank you for clarification!